# 200 amp panel box with some circuits not working

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, electrical-panel

I have a 200 amp breaker box in a mobile home. The power just suddenly goes out on all but two breakers/circuits. Each functional circuit is on opposite sides of the panel; the left side is one breaker down, while the right one is one up from the last. The functional circuits on the left side go up to the ceiling, so do the non-functional ones. The right is the same, except those go down under the floor.

There was no sound when it happened, no flickers, just suddenly out except these two. No breakers flipped, and there is no smell of burnt wiring.

I have flipped all breakers back and forth several times including the main and disconnect outside.

I am just perplexed as to cause. It is raining a lot but no more than usual. The inside of the box appears dry.

Do you have any idea what to look for?

Comment: Please add a photo of the inside of the service panel to your question.  Since you have low reputation, you might have to upload it elsewhere (https://imgur.com/ use "upload image" button at top) and link to it in your question.

Comment: It's hard to tell from your description, but if it's every other breaker on each side, and any double breakers (240v) that are out, then it sounds like you lost one of your hot legs. That will likely be upstream of the breaker panel.

Comment: Have you tried to call your utility? It is very possible the problem is on their end.

Answer (score 1):

Wow! You got some mobile home with a 200 amp service.
The code says:

> II. Mobile and Manufactured Homes
>
> 550.10 Power Supply.
>
> (A) Feeder. The power supply to the mobile home shall be a feeder assembly consisting of not more than one listed 50-ampere mobile home power-supply cord or a permanently installed feeder.

Maybe you have a modular home?

I agree with BMitch though sounds like you lost a leg on the utility feed. You should call your utility. Might be a tree limb took out one wire of your service.

Comment: What's your point?? A 100A or 200A service is not at all uncommon to a modern mobile home. ..................... I hope you are not misinterpreting the section you quoted to limit all feeders to a mobile to 50A.

Comment: The 50 amps is for a mobile home feeder, I believe what you are talking about would probably be classified as a manufactured home (550.32(B)) since they will be attached to a foundation. The code defines that a mobile home has a "permanent chassis" and is not designed to be attached permanently to a foundation hence the cord instead of a service. A slight difference but a difference nonetheless and most modern homes are not designed to be mobile.

Comment: No, I am talking about a mobile home, on a steel chassis. Most now come with a 100A or 200A service. I have not seen a 50A cord connected mobile in years. ..... Point is, it's 50A if it's got a cord, or larger if it's a "permanent feeder".

Comment: Ahhh! I see. Well it's not the first time the Code was behind the industry practice. Thanks for the info I will remember that for future reference.